# In git extension is it possible to commit and merge into a different branch in one action?

Tags: git, git-extensions

We have a Master and QA branches. For each task I create a new branch T1.
I develop on T1 than merge to QA, and merge back to master once approved.

So, during dev, I waste a lot of time on commit+push/switch branch (QA)/merge T1 to QA/push/switch branch (T1).

I'm looking for a way to automate this process in git/git extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git aliases. You can make a list of commands to execute and set them to a single command.

I've made a straightforward example from your question. Adapt this for your actual needs. Add this to your config file:

```
[alias]
    commitlikeapro = "!f() { git commit -m \"" ${1} "\" && git push origin T1 && git checkout qa && git merge T1 && git push origin qa && git checkout T1; }; f"
```

Then you can use it as:

```
git commitlikeapro "new message"
```

Sources:

- http://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases for documentation.
- http://haacked.com/archive/2014/07/28/github-flow-aliases/ for useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow looks a lot like `git-flow feature`.
Here `develop` is your `QA` branch.

Comment: it's looks useful and has similar feature to what I asked, but not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the 1st push as it's not necessary (and you can keep your T1 branch local, without never pushing it).

This way you can also use `git rebase QA` to make your commit tree grows right and simplify a lot the merge and code review.

Comment: This is a good idea, but still takes too long since I have to switch branches, also rebase ask me to stash files which is even more work...

Comment: keeping your code well organized does not make "more work". It's a little more organization for a lot less of useless work

Comment: for sure - but this question is about keeping organized code with LESS work... see the question above for a good solution